# Create random number without duplicating

Tags: ms-access, random, vba

I am trying to troubleshoot an existing Access database application that is supposed to generate a random number between 1 and the number of records in the table. This is done for 2o different tables with a varying amount of records. The tables with less records are displaying duplicate numbers of the 10 that it is supposed to display and write to a separate table. I assume the same would happen with the larger tables but with more numbers to choose from I was just unable to duplicate the issue.

Here is a sampling of the code with error handling removed:

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstRecords As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim tdfNew As TableDef
Dim fldNew As Field
Dim i As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim Check As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstRecords = db.OpenRecordset("customer_table")

     rstRecords.MoveLast
     FindRecordCount = rstRecords.RecordCount
     i = rstRecords.RecordCount
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Unique_numbers"

'--- create the table
Set tdfNew = db.CreateTableDef("Unique_numbers")
'--- add text field (length 20)
Set fldNew = tdfNew.CreateField("customer_table", dbLong)
'--- save the new field
tdfNew.Fields.Append fldNew

'--- save the new table design
db.TableDefs.Append tdfNew

'---Initialize your recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Unique_numbers", dbOpenDynaset)


'Dim i As Integer
'Dim K As Integer
'Dim Check As String

'i = TxtInput
  TxtInput = i
  K = 0
  Check = T

Do
  Do While K < 11
    'K = K + 1
        Randomize
          If K = 0 Then
            TxtOutput = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput
            rs.Update
            K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 1 Then
            TxtOutput2 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput2
            rs.Update
            K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 2 Then
             TxtOutput3 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput3
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 3 Then
             TxtOutput4 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput4
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 4 Then
             TxtOutput5 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput5
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 5 Then
             TxtOutput6 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput6
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 6 Then
             TxtOutput7 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput7
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
          ElseIf K = 7 Then
             TxtOutput8 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput8
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
           ElseIf K = 8 Then
             TxtOutput9 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput9
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
           ElseIf K = 9 Then
             TxtOutput10 = Fix(i * Rnd) + 1
             rs.AddNew
             rs.Fields(0).Value = TxtOutput10
             rs.Update
             K = K + 1
             Check = f
            Exit Do
          End If
    Loop
Loop Until Check = f
```

Comment: What is `Check = T` supposed to do?  Is `T` defined somewhere?

Comment: Why the loop with an If/ElseIf structure that does something unique for each loop index?  I suppose that is a stylistic question, but it makes the code much longer than it needs to be.

Comment: The most honest answer I can give you is "I don't know. I didn't write it." I am just trying to fix the random number issue without recreating the wheel. If it needs to be changed I will change it but I don't feel the need to do so for style reasons.

Comment: Check is defined as a string and initialized to T and then in the last part of the loop it is equal to F. Again I guess this was just a style preference. That aspect of it works it is just that the numbers sometimes duplicate within the ten that are being displayed.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your database?

Comment: Thanks but no I cannot

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Randomize VBA function re-initializes the random number generator seed.  Without arugments, it uses the system timer as the seed.

You are re-initializing it every loop iteration, before each call to Rnd.  Given that there might not be very much time between calls to Randomize, you might be restarting the random number generator over and over again at the same point, thus leading to repeated numbers.

Try calling Randomize once at the top of your code.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I tried that and it still does not work.

Comment: Hmm... How many are duplicated per run?  There is always a good chance of _some_ duplication, as Rnd does not provide uniqueness (and this is especially clear when you multiply by a smallish number of rows and truncate to an integer).  Do you need to randomly select without replacement (like shuffling a deck of cards), rather than doing what you are doing now (which is like selecting a card, replacing it in the deck, and drawing again)?

Comment: I do need to randomly select without replacement. But only for each run. The next time the button is clicked a number can be chosen again.

Answer (score 0):

Generating random number is not an issue. Generating random unique number is not an issue either. However, choosing a random number from a range, that has not been chosen already requires track of used numbers. The issue is when it comes to performance especially if you want to read/update values from a table and check if the ID has been used already.

You have two options. (maybe more that i can't think of right now)

- If you are using VBA to update your table. You can create a public function with public array contains list of used and unused numbers.
- If you are using SQL query to update your table again you can use a public function to get a random number but instead of arrays you will perform random choice with where condition ID not already used in the new table.

first method would look like this:
You send min and max values from your range and get a value back which is not used yet. An array or holder will be used to keep track of your used and unused numbers. I used dictionary but you can use arrays or arrays with dictionary.

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mNumbers As Object
Private mSession_ID As Long

Public Function FN_GET_RANDOM_NO(iMin As Long, iMax As Long) As Long
    FN_GET_RANDOM_NO = Int((iMax - iMin + 1) * Rnd + iMin)
End Function

Public Function FN_RANDOM_INIT_COLLECTION(iSession_id As Long, iMin As Long, iMax As Long) As Object
    Set mNumbers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i, J As Long
    mSession_ID = iSession_id
    J = 0
    For i = iMin To iMax
        J = J + 1
        mNumbers.Add J, i
    Next i
End Function

Public Function FN_RANDOM_READ_UNUSED_NO() As Long
    Dim ID As Long
    ID = FN_GET_RANDOM_NO(1, mNumbers.count)
    FN_RANDOM_READ_UNUSED_NO = mNumbers(ID)
    If mNumbers.exists(ID) Then mNumbers.Remove ID

    Dim tmpDic As Object
    Set tmpDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each item In mNumbers
        i = i + 1
        tmpDic.Add i, mNumbers(item)
    Next item

    Set mNumbers = tmpDic

End Function
Public Function FN_GET_UNUSED_NO(iSession_id As Long, iMin As Long, iMax As Long) As Long
    If mSession_ID = iSession_id Then
        If Not mNumbers Is Nothing Then
READ_AFTER:
            FN_GET_UNUSED_NO = FN_RANDOM_READ_UNUSED_NO
        Else
INIT:
            'initialize the table
            FN_RANDOM_INIT_COLLECTION iSession_id, iMin, iMax
            GoTo READ_AFTER:
        End If
    Else
        'new session reload the used number collection
        Set mNumbers = Nothing
        GoTo INIT
    End If
End Function
```

get a random unique id form your range simply by:

```
FN_GET_UNUSED_NO(1,10, 50)
```

session_id is there to identify you are accessing the collection within one session. Different id would re initialize the unused table. Expand the code if you want to manage more than one collection. Maybe with an array.

it will return 0 if there aren't anymore numbers to return.

result will look like this:

```
?FN_GET_UNUSED_NO(1,10, 50)
 0 
 10 
 50 
 11 
 16 
 40 
 18 
 25 
 22 
 33 
 30 
 14 
 26 
 49 
 45 
 39 
 20 
 35 
 17 
 15 
 38 
 27 
 48 
 12 
 43 
 24 
 46 
 37 
 41 
 28 
 31 
 34 
 19 
 47 
 29 
 13 
 21 
 44 
 36 
 32 
 23 
 42
```

second method is fairly simple you just retrieve a random value, check if the value is already assigned in the new table.

Comment: Since the data is written to the table each time through the loop I am wondering how I would go about having it check the column to see if the new assigned value already exists before writing it to the table.